Forgetting the pronunciation of certain words (expat)
As an English expat, I've noticed that especially over the last few years (I've been abroad for 8 years and counting) I've started to forget the exact pronunciation of certain words. It's annoying and I've no clue how to fix it (aside from going back to the UK).
Examples:
Exponent: uhk·spow·nuhnt (accent in the second syllable) -> uhk·spo·nuhnt (accent in the first syllable)
Twinings: twy·nings -> twi·nnings (I think some Australians also tend to mispronounce this one)
Dover: dou·ver -> do·vver
Asymmetric: ay·symmetric -> a·symmetric
(the list goes on but these have been the latest offenders)
Any ideas or resources that I could use? I suppose this is the annoying thing about English ... it has no rules when it comes to pronunciation. I just hope I manage to fix this at some point. And yes, the culprit is German :').

English ... it has no rules when it comes to pronunciation - you said it!

@MichaelHarvey Still it's frustrating not being able to do anything about it

I suppose I'd offer the same advice that I would to a foreign learner with a different first language: listen to/watch the BBC. It's not the same as being here, but you'd pick up a lot.

Why would you not pronounce the first syllable of exponent as 'ek'? And Dover is, of course, Doh-ver.

@KateBunting That's how Google writes the phonemes. Another way would be: ekspóhnent (correct pronunciation) éksponnent (my pronunciation)

I recommend you take this opportunity to switch to an american accent. Why not. The Joe Rogan podcast has very interesting guests, and it's a never-ending source of content. "The total length of all 2398 JRE podcasts (excluding sponsored ad reads) is 6,325 hours with an average episode duration of 2hrs 38min 16sec. Listening to every single episode of The Joe Rogan Experience non-stop would take about 264 days or over 8.5 months."

@Sam Why the hell would I do that ...

There is a youtuber (Jade) who teaches British English and pronunciation. She occasionally laments social class consciousness. You must adjust your accent to not appear to be a lower class worker, and vice versa, if you want to fit in. What a pain to worry about that. The american accent is egalitarian.  Less risk of sounding either too posh, or not enough.

@Sam as long as I'm a Brit I will not be doing that. No one should care about dumb opinions. If people judge me because of my accent it says a lot about them.

You need to find some English speakers to hang out with. There is correct and incorrect pronunciation. Take the word development: the tonic stress is on ve. And often French speakers will try to place the accent on the ment. Some words are stressed differently in American and British English. Big deal.

The main issue is losing track of English (regardless of dialect), so any sources of language input, or practice, would help. If you watch a movie, or listen to an audio book, it's going to be 98% the same between American and British, and you still get a refresher class that way.
